# How to use GROUP BY method in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I’m trying to use "group by" instead of "DISTINCT" in my php file to select some rows that all of them have an specific column value and it’s "idchat". 
And I want to get more than one columns
please help me!

I’ve checked every pages but I didn’t understand enything

```
 <?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","---","pass","---");
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $mobile = $_GET["mobile"];
    $idchat = $_GET["idchat"];

    if (strpos($mobile, '9') !== false) {

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d,idchat  FROM database where mobile = '$mobile' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $array[] = $row;    
}
header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);?>
```

and this code gives me this error:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/---/test.php on line 12

Comment: Why do you want to 'GROUP BY', in stead of 'DISTINCT' ? What are you trying to do?

Comment: That query is invalid.. You can't ORDER BY on a column which is not in the DISTINCT clause..

Comment: [database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D) is a reserved word.

Comment: @Raymond In MySQL you can do that.

Comment: Could you explain more I am not enough acquaintance

Comment: *"In MySQL you can do that"* @Luuk in old versions maybe but it's not correct ANSI/ISO SQL also see what happens in more modern version where the sql_mode is [enabled](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hLTT1TZ5Ec3UMfN35bQbm2/0) .. Also if you can does not mean it's good..

Comment: @Raymond: I recently install 8.0 on my Windows machine, so it's 'default', and MySQL does not complain.

Comment: @Parsopi:  [mysql_query](https://php.net/mysqli_query)  returns FALSE when something is wrong. You should check for it, and not continue. In this case it's the reserved word `database`.

Answer (score 0):

See next output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM database;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database' at line 1
mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.mytable' doesn't exist
ERROR:
No query specified

mysql>
```

The first query is not understood because database is a reserved word. You should not use that to name a table. A work around is to add backquotes around the name:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `database`;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.database' doesn't exist
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Could you correct my codes please?": Ok, but untested:

```
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","---","pass","---");
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $mobile = $_GET["mobile"];
    $idchat = $_GET["idchat"];

    if (strpos($mobile, '9') !== false) {

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d,idchat,id  FROM `database` where mobile = '$mobile' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $array[] = $row;    
    }
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
}
else {
  echo mysqli_error($connection);
}
mysqli_close($connection);?>
}
```

I also did add `id` to the query because of comment from @Raymond

Comment: thank for your complete answer ! !
but 
after I replaced  
`SELECT a,b,c,d,idchat,id  FROM database where mobile = $mobile GROUP BY idchat`


it gave this error :

`Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column database.a which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`
 how can I fix it ?

Comment: I will repeat my question: 'Why do you want to 'GROUP BY', ?'

Comment: Because with DISTINCT I myself cannot get more than one column and want about 6 columns value after selsect with just one criterion . but with DISTINCT I can just get the column that I order my select query.

Comment: You definitely have to follow a (MY)SQL course pretty quick...!!